# Difference between a twb and twbx

Tags: tableau-api

Please provide some information about difference between twb workbook with extract and twbx workbook. Also I am facing some issues, I have workbook(twbx) on Tableau Server which use published extract. Extract was refreshed today. But workbook shows old data....

Comment: Are any alerts showing in Tableau Server (log in as an admin and look at the top right of the screen, just beside your login name)? If so, this will give an indication if the extract refresh completely successfully or failed.

Answer (score 5):

- TWB - XML file for your Tableau Workbook, contains all the selections and layout you've made. It does not contain data. These tend to be very small.
- TWBX - zipped file that contains the TWB as well as data used by TWB in an extract

Here's some more info from the Tableau website.
http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/sending-packaged-workbook

Try closing & opening your workbook. If that doesn't refr

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the data at the path or database connection that the Tableau Server points to the exact source you wish to refresh from.

Remember the Server may have different drives mounted, different firewall rules. If you are reading from a file like Excel or Access to create your extract; changing the version of the file elsewhere on the file system won't affect the extract on the Tableau Server if that extract points elsewhere (kind of obvious, but often forgotten, especially if a copy of the Excel file is bundled up into the twbx file).

It is also often a good idea in production to publish a data source and extract separately from the workbooks that use it so that they can be updated independently. Look under the data menu to find the publish command.

Answer (score 1):

TWBX is intended for sharing. [It does not link to the original file source](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/twb-vs-twbx-in-tableau/); instead it contains a copy of the data that was obtained when the file was created.

If you need to give them TWBX, you can create a TWB as a template and then use it to create TWBX when your data source is updated. Your clients will get a TWBX that they want and you don't have to do anything.

You can even have a batch process for that. Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Odk2xr6qOoQ

Comment: Could you please add more details? If those links die, your answer dies.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned, the twbx file contains its own data extract. Since you have a twbx file that uses a published data extract as its source, you basically created an extract of the original extract. In other words, the data is not coming from the published extract anymore, but is self-contained in the workbook itself, so refreshing the published extract won't update your workbook.

You can try scheduling the workbook itself (after the refresh of the extract of course). However, that didn't work for me, and I always have to refresh the extract manually from the Tableau Desktop.